# Rotate monitor to portrait on Windows Server 2003 with ATI card

Tags: display, windows-server-2003, rotate, amd-graphics-card

Does anyone know if it is possible to rotate a monitor from landscape to portrait mode on Windows Server 2003 32-bit with an ATI video card?

According to Dell's site, I should be able to rotate my Dell P2310H monitor by installing drivers from their website, but they don't have drivers for Windows Server 2003.  I let Windows Update search for the driver (with the driver CD that came with the monitor in my drive) and it did install drivers, but I still don't see any options for rotating.

Some people say that the ATI Catalyst Control Center allows for monitor rotation, but I've never been able to run that software on Windows Server 2003. A google search reports that others have the same problem.

Has anyone successfully figured out how to rotate a monitor on Windows Server 2003 with an ATI card?

Comment: Try the drivers for XP, they often work on Server 2003.

Comment: I wonder what is the make and model of your video card. Physical ability to rotate the monitor does not add capabilities to hardware.

Comment: Does it work the same as the old trick CTRL+ALT+ARROW KEY?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ATI cards without CCC and **[EeeRotate](http://vk.edward.li.googlepages.com/eeerotate)** works fine for me.

EeeRotate combines iRotate (to rotate the display) and Sakasamouse (to 'rotate' the mouse/touchpad). It's freeware and portable (doesn't have to be installed)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to work for me. I just installed [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm), but selecting a different rotation has no effect. EeeRotate appeared to rotate how my mouse works, but not my monitor.

Comment: strange, Win2k3 is using the same drivers as XP. iRotate only rotates the display, EeeRotate is also using Sakasamouse to flip the mouse the same way. if iRotate doesn't work, then of course EeeRotate will only rotate the mouse. I only have a virtual Win2k3 installation at the moment, can't test it physically.

Answer (score 0):

EeeRotate rotated only rotated primary monitor iRotate worked fine with two monitors.